# Make elements fill the remaining space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple HTML document. I have a `header`, a `section` and a `div` (that contains an unknown number of other `divs`).

The header and the section do not (and can not) have set heights. Their height comes from the content. Only their width is known (set to 100%).

Is it possible, with flexbox or other means, to get each of those child `divs`, in this case with `class="fill"` to be the height of the body - **minus the header and section**?

In other words, when someone goes to the page, I want them to see the header and the section and then have the first `div.fill` reach all the way to the bottom, forcing them to scroll to see the next div (but not scroll to see the bottom of the first child `div`).

I am using a templating system so unfortunately the structure of the HTML can not change and I would like to do this only in CSS.

```html
<html>
  <body>
      <header> Header content, might contain an image</header>
      <section> This is the sub header, unknown height </section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="fill">I Want</div>
        <div class="fill">Each of These</div>
        <div class="fill">To be </div>
        <div class="fill">The height of the body - the Header - the Section</div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is a JS based solution suitable?

Comment: No, I can not use JS for this :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;                   /* 1 */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.fill { flex: 0 0 100%; }    /* 2 */

header  { background-color: aqua; }
section { background-color: orange; }
.fill:nth-child(odd) { background-color: yellow; }
.fill:nth-child(even) { background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<body>
  <header> Header content, might contain an image</header>
  <section> This is the sub header, unknown height </section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fill">I Want</div>
    <div class="fill">Each of These</div>
    <div class="fill">To be </div>
    <div class="fill">The height of the body - the Header - the Section</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tajvm6kk/4/)

Notes:

1. The `flex-grow: 1` component of `flex: 1` tells the `.container` element (a flex item child of `body`) to consume all remaining space. This will cause `.container` to use up any space not consumed by `header` and `section`.
2. The `flex-basis: 100%` component of `flex: 0 0 100%` tells the `.fill` items (flex item children of `.container`) to consume 100% height of the parent. So these items will always take the full height of `flex-grow: 1` on the parent.

   Because flex items are set, by default, to shrink in order to not overflow the container, an override is set with `flex-shrink: 0` in the `flex: 0 0 100%` rule. This disables the shrinking feature and allows the items to stay fixed at 100% height. (Otherwise, regardless of the defined `height` / `flex-basis`, the items would shrink evenly to prevent an overflow. See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tajvm6kk/5/).)

Comment: I like this solution, but unfortunately this cuts off some of the first div.  I am using an image so I would prefer to not have the bottom of the image cut off at first.

Comment: Not sure it's possible with pure CSS. I've got everything set up, but we need to tell each `.fill` item to occupy the full height of the container. CSS can only tell them to distribute the available height amongst themselves. You may need JS. https://jsfiddle.net/tajvm6kk/2/

Comment: Your answers are both very good and very close, it's much appreciated. It seems like there should be a way to do this.

Comment: Hi @Startec, I updated my answer. With newer browser versions, which allow percentage heights to use flex heights for reference ([traditionally they could only reference fixed heights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)), your layout is now possible in pure CSS. Tested in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the structure of the elements a bit you can get it with only css.
Basically add the first `.fill` element in a container with the header and the section (let's call it `first`). For the other divs use `height: 100vh`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.fill {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.first {
  flex: 1;
}

header { background-color: aqua; }
section { background-color: orange; }
.first, .fill:nth-child(odd) { background-color: yellow; }
.fill:nth-child(even) { background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header> Header content, might contain an image</header>
    <section> This is the sub header, unknown height </section>
    <div class="first">I Want</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fill">Each of These</div>
  <div class="fill">To be </div>
  <div class="fill">The height of the body - the Header - the Section</div>

</body>
</html>
```